# Python ftplib - any way to shut it up?

Tags: python, ftplib

I am writing a test harness in python and as part of the testing I need to initialise an FTP server and upload various files. I am using ftplib and everything is working ok. The only problem I have is that I am seeing loads of FTP text appearing in the console window intermixed with my test results, which makes scanning the results quite tricky. I haven't found a way to shut ftp lib up and stop this happening, does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: Strange, I've used ftplib before and I did not see this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually pass empty (or otherwise customized) callbacks to at least [retrlines](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) and [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.dir).  By default they print to stdout (questionable design).  By default calls (probably for debugging) like

```
myFTP.retrlines(command)
myFTP.dir(someDir)
```

will print to your terminal.  Remove them or use custom callbacks:

```
myFTP.retrlines(command, retrlinesCallback)
myFTP.dir(someDir, dirCallback)
```

`retrlinesCallback` and `dirCallback` functions could have logic to e.g. print to the terminal only if debugging is enabled.

There is also a [set_debuglevel](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.set_debuglevel) option.  The default is 0 (no debugging), but it might be set higher somewhere in the code.